# Unable to render custom tool with 'react-editor-js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, editorjs

I can't seem to make my custom tool work with 'react-editor-js' library or maybe I just don't know how to do so, this is the custom tool I'm using in the backend for adding 'anchor' field into tunes of the block.

```
export default class AnchorTune {
  /**
   * Current anchor
   * @returns {bool}
   */
  static get isTune() {
    return true
  }

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param api - Editor.js API
   * @param data - previously saved data
   */
  constructor({ api, data }) {
    this.api = api
    this.data = {
      anchor: undefined
    }

    if (data && data.anchor) {
      this.anchor = data.anchor
    }

    this._CSS = {
      classWrapper: 'cdx-anchor-tune-wrapper',
      classIcon: 'cdx-anchor-tune-icon',
      classInput: 'cdx-anchor-tune-input'
    }
  }

  /**
   * Current anchor
   * @returns {string}
   */
  get anchor() {
    return this.data.anchor || ''
  }

  /**
   * Set anchor
   * @param {string} anchor - anchor ID
   */
  set anchor(anchor) {
    // Allow only the following characters
    anchor = anchor.replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/gi, '')

    if (anchor.length > 0) {
      this.data.anchor = anchor
    } else {
      this.data.anchor = undefined
    }
  }

  /**
   * Rendering tune wrapper
   * @returns {HTMLDivElement}
   */
  render() {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    wrapper.classList.add(this._CSS.classWrapper)

    const wrapperIcon = document.createElement('div')
    wrapperIcon.classList.add(this._CSS.classIcon)
    wrapperIcon.innerHTML =
      '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve" width="12px" height="12px"><g><g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="hash"><path style="" d="M30,12V8h-5.004l1-8h-4l-1,8h-7.998l1-8h-4l-1,8H2v4h6.498L7.5,20H2v4h5l-1,8h4l1-8h8l-1.002,8H22    l1-8h7v-4h-6.5l0.996-8H30z M19.5,20h-8l0.998-8h7.998L19.5,20z" fill="#878787" data-original="#030104" class=""/></g></g></svg>'

    const wrapperInput = document.createElement('input')
    wrapperInput.placeholder = this.api.i18n.t('Anchor')
    wrapperInput.classList.add(this._CSS.classInput)
    wrapperInput.value = this.anchor

    wrapperInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
      // Save anchor and remove invalid charachers
      this.anchor = event.target.value
      event.target.value = this.anchor
    })

    wrapper.appendChild(wrapperIcon)
    wrapper.appendChild(wrapperInput)

    return wrapper
  }

  /**
   * Save
   * @returns {{anchor: string} | undefined}
   */
  save() {
    if (!this.data.anchor) {
      return undefined
    }

    return this.data
  }
}
```

I've tried to copy this tool from the BE project and call it similar to other tools like so

```
export const EDITOR_JS_TOOLS = {
  linkTool: LinkTool,
  image: Image,
  quote: Quote,
  list: List,
  header: Header,
  delimiter: Delimiter,
  table: Table,
  nestedlist: NestedList,
  anchor: AnchorTune
}
```